# error somewhere in the code while adding colorscale in dash barplot

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have written some code to represent a barplot with a colorscale, in dash. The expected result looks something like this but with only one dropdown menu

https://brandatastudio.shinyapps.io/visualization-practica/

, therefore I wrote the following code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()
datause = pd.read_csv("datawind.csv" , sep = ",")






app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Graph(
       id = 'barplot1'),
dcc.Dropdown(
       id="dropmenu" ,
       options=[{'label' : i , 'value' : i } for i in datause.columns.values
],
       value='Total Investment ($ Millions)')

],
)

@app.callback(Output(component_id = 'barplot1', component_property = 'figure'),
              [Input(component_id = 'dropmenu' , component_property = 'value')])
def update_figure(dropmenuinput):

    potato = dropmenuinput
    return {
        'data':  [
        go.Bar(
        x = datause["State"],
        y = datause[potato],
        mode = 'markers',
            marker = {
                "color" : datause[potato],
                "colorbar" : dict(title = "hola"),
                "colorscale" : 'Viridis'
                })],
        'layout': go.Layout(
        title = "pene"
        ,xaxis={'title': "state"},
        yaxis ={'title' : potato})  }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Instead, the obtained results ends up looking like this 
[image]

After testing and retesting, I discover that the main error of the code seems to be in this section

```
mode = 'markers',
marker = dict(
    size=16,
    color = datause['Total Investment ($ Millions)'],
    colorbar = dict(title = "hola"),
    colorscale = 'Viridis'
    ))]
```

If I remove that section of the code, the dashboard looks something like it should, without the colorscale of course.

[image]

So, the question is, what is failing in my insertion of the colorscale? I have been checking different posts of how to add them 
https://community.plot.ly/t/add-a-colorbar-to-scatter-plot-in-python/13349

https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/#custom-contour-plot-colorscale

and I find no examples applied to dash dashboard, or barplots, only here can I hope to find help.

Notes: Heres is the information regarding to the enviroment and packages affecting:

```
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Cython==0.28.2
dash==0.21.0
dash-core-components==0.22.1
dash-html-components==0.10.0
dash-renderer==0.12.1
decorator==4.3.0
nbformat==4.4.0
numpy==1.14.2
pandas==0.22.0
pandas-datareader==0.6.0
plotly==2.5.1
python-dateutil==2.7.2
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Here is the dataset Iḿ using https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cr74jKf2FHDA7XVAblQX3d9_dVHfXyVG

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is the line

```
mode = 'markers',
```

inside the `go.Bar`. If you go to the [reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar) you will see that Bar traces do not have this attribute. If it still doesn't work I suggest updating plotly, as version 3 was a major upgrade to the library (actually I would recommend updating even if it works).

Here is a minimal example from a notebook:

```
trace = go.Bar(
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    marker = {
        "color" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "colorbar" : dict(),
        "colorscale" : 'Viridis',
        "showscale": True
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: removed that line and updated, and no improvement. Thanks for the answer at least

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue when adding a color scale to a Map using Dash and the way I resolved this was by finding out the underlying colour schemes by running the code:

```
import plotly.express as px

print(px.colors.sequential.Plasma)

['#0d0887', '#46039f', '#7201a8', '#9c179e', '#bd3786', '#d8576b', '#ed7953', '#fb9f3a', '#fdca26', '#f0f921']
```

Then my command in Dash is:

```
"colorscale":[[0.0,'#0d0887'], [0.1,'#46039f'], [0.2,'#7201a8'], [0.3,'#9c179e'], [0.4,'#bd3786'], [0.5,'#d8576b'], [0.6,'#ed7953'], [0.7,'#fb9f3a'], [0.8,'#fdca26'], [1.0,'#f0f921']]
```